# .NET Core: access request data on bad request when ApiController shortcuts the pipeline

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, asp.net-core-webapi, .net-core-2.2

For all those stumbling accross logging issues I created a small public playground on [Github](https://github.com/MontyGvMC/dot-net-core-logging-demo-api). Feel free to join.

---

I am still experimenting with the one hits all logging filter for my requests.

The goal is simple. Instead of writing the logs in each controller method implement them once in a filter (or middleware) and apply them globally to all. This is used when something wents wrong I can see which data was used causing the problem.

so for example a controller action (with the globally applied filter)

```
[HttpPut("{id:int}")
public IActionResult UpdateModel(int id, [FromBody] MyRequestModel request) {}
```

would create logs like

```
[Timestamp] INFO: MyNamespace.Controllers.MyModelController.UpdateModel
{ 
  "Parameters": {
     "Id": 1,
     "Request": {
       "Name": "abc",
       "SomeInt": 3
     }
  }
}
```

Pretty, no more logging manually in each method.

But wait: it's an API and I used the [ApiController] attribute and the request model has invalid data (let's say Name = "a" but it needs to be at least of length of 3).

This gives me 3 problems

1. ActionFilter.OnActionExecuting is shortcutted and does not get called (due to the ApiController)
2. the binding of the arguments seems to be skipped and the bound (invalid) data is not applied to the ActionArguments
3. only the ResultFilter.OnResultExecuted is called but there seems to be no way for accessing/logging the invalid data

This somehow means logging works only when everything goes well but aren't the most interesting logs those were things go wrong?

```
public void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext context)
  {
    _loggerFactory
    .CreateLogger(context.ActionDescriptor.DisplayName.Split(" ")[0])
    .LogInformation
    (
      JsonConvert.SerializeObject
      (
        new { Parameters = context.ActionArguments },
        Formatting.Indented
      )
    );
  }
```

Point 1: I of course could remove the ApiController from each controller and go back to return BadRequest results manually. But I like the centralized approach and would like to stick with it.

I liked the model binding approach giving me classes to serialize for the logs (instead of reading the request body manually as one string). With a custom Json contract resolver I am able to mark model properties as sensitive and they are hidden in the logs (for those how care about security).

So my actual question:

Is there a way to get the model binding values in a ResultFilter or are they thrown away totally?
Or is there a way to hook into the model binding/model validation and write the logs there before they get thrown away?
Both especially for the case where the ApiController attribute starts shortcutting the filter pipeline.

---

```
public class LogFilter : IActionFilter, IResultFilter, IExceptionFilter
{

    private readonly ILoggerFactory _loggerFactory;

    public LogFilter(ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
    {
      _loggerFactory = loggerFactory ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(loggerFactory));
    }

    public void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext context)
    {
      _loggerFactory
         .CreateLogger(context.ActionDescriptor.DisplayName.Split(" ")[0])
         .LogInformation
         (
           JsonConvert.SerializeObject
           (
             new
             {
               RequestBody = ReadBodyAsString(context.HttpContext.Request),
               Parameter = context.ActionArguments
             },
             Formatting.Indented
           )
         );
    }

    public void OnActionExecuted(ActionExecutedContext context) {}      

    public void OnResultExecuting(ResultExecutingContext context)
    {
        if (!context.ModelState.IsValid)
        {
          _loggerFactory
            .CreateLogger(context.ActionDescriptor.DisplayName.Split(" ")[0])
            .LogWarning
            (
               JsonConvert.SerializeObject
               (
                 new
                 {
                   RequestBody = ReadBodyAsString(context.HttpContext.Request),
                   ModelErrors = context.ModelState
                    .Where(kvp => kvp.Value.Errors.Count > 0)
                    .ToDictionary
                    (
                      kvp => kvp.Key,
                      kvp => kvp.Value.Errors.Select(e => e.ErrorMessage).ToArray()
                    )
                 },
                 Formatting.Indented
               )
            );
        }
    }

    public void OnResultExecuted(ResultExecutedContext context) {}

    public void OnException(ExceptionContext context)
    {

        _loggerFactory
        .CreateLogger(context.ActionDescriptor.DisplayName.Split(" ")[0])
        .LogError
        (
          context.Exception,
          JsonConvert.SerializeObject
          (
            new
            {
              //RequestBody = ReadBodyAsString(context.HttpContext.Request) // body is disposed here
            },
            Formatting.Indented
          )
        );

    }
}
```

Comment: Are you sure you're using `System.Web.Http.Filters.ActionFilterAttribute` and not `System.Web.Mvc.ActionFilterAttribute`? Note the namespace.

Comment: I would say none of them because I implement the interfaces IActionFilter and IResultFilter from the Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Filters namespace.

Comment: Ah, right, .NET Core. My bad.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a class which implements OnActionExecuting method of IActionFilter. And register it in global filter so that it applies to all controllers and actions. When exception happens for model binding(coz of length), your OnActionExecuting method still gets called even when [ApiController] is used and you can log it there.

Eg.

```
public class MyActionFilterAttribute: IActionFilter
{
    public void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext context)
    {
        //Your logic to log the request, you can get the details from
        //context parameter

        //You can check if model state is valid also by using the property
        //context.ModelState.IsValid
    }
}
```

In Startup.cs, you need to set SuppressModelStateInvalidFilter to true. This will not return the 400 status automatically. Your controller method still gets called and since you have action filter, the OnActionExecuting gets called.

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddMvc(
            config =>
            {
                config.Filters.Add(new MyActionFilterAttribute());
            })
            .ConfigureApiBehaviorOptions(options =>
            {
                options.SuppressModelStateInvalidFilter = true;
            });
    }
```

Comment: Are you sure? I tested it and OnException gets called for real exceptions (as I used it for logging exceptions) but not for ModelValidation errors

Comment: @monty, have updated the answer after verifying. Please check now.

Comment: yes, setting SuppressModelStateInvalidFilter to true will again hit the controller action and call the filters. But then there is again the need to check for invalid model states in the controllers (which not needing was the beauty of using the ApiController). Checkout scenario 2 for my experiments solving it: https://github.com/MontyGvMC/dot-net-core-logging-demo-api

Comment: well, seems the best way to go for now is suppressModelStateInvalidFilter in combination with a second global BadRequestFilter in the correct order. So there are both benefits (the ones of the ApiController and the one of centralized logging).

Comment: @monty, as mentioned, currently only way is to check ModelState.IsValid and return. We could rquest for a feature from Microsoft/open source contributers to provide a filter which only calls if there is any error in model validation even when [ApiController] is used.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are right about the ActionFilter only catch successful requests. 
For your invalid requests, maybe you can have a look at the [InvalidModelStateResponseFactory](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/web-api/index?view=aspnetcore-2.2#customize-badrequest-response).

When using options.InvalidModelStateResponseFactory you can read your Model and validationerrors.

Comment: puh, indeed a possible way to go but I am cracking my brain how to add logging there.

Comment: Someone had the same issue, and solved it [this way](https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetCore.Docs/issues/12157#issuecomment-487756787)

Comment: Thanks for the link. The code helped me a few steps. For the last steps I opened this issue: https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetCore.Docs/issues/13720